# paint in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

I have developed a drawing program in `Android Studio` with `kotlin` and I have placed a `seekbar` to change the width of the lines, but when I change the `seekbar`, the lines I have already drawn also change, which is not desirable.
I will upload any part of the code you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In order for us to help you, please edit your question and add the relevant parts of the code. Show how you change the width of the lines and how the lines are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess here, I'll edit my answer if we get more info.

I'm assuming that you are using the `onDraw(Canvas)` function or something similar and in this function you are using a `Paint` to draw the lines each frame.

The problem is probably there, the `Paint` you are using isn't instanced. It seems that you are using the same object for all the lines, what you have to do is to have a different `Paint` object for each line or for each state of the seekbar.